# Learning Deep Generative Models of Graphs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, generative-models

I'm reading through [Learning Deep Generative Models of Graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03324.pdf), which is a paper that seems to me propose some sort of variational autoencoder to generate a graph.

At very high level the semantic of what the network would is insert new nodes and connecting existing nodes, which is pretty straightforward to understand apparently.

However the first doubt I have is how to make this *decisions* differentiable, so we can apply backpropagation.

It seems to me the key is in understanding equations (5),(6), (7), (8), (9) and (10) in section 4.1., which I write down for reference

$$
\begin{array}{l}
h_V^{(T)} = prop^{(T)}(h_V,G)  \\
h_G = R(h_V^{(T)},G) \\
f_{addnode}(G) = softmax(f_{an}(h_G)) \\
f_{addedge}(G,v) = \sigma(f_{ae}(h_G,h_v^{(T)}) \\
s_u = f_s(h_u^{(T)},h_v^{(T)}) \\
f_{nodes}(G,v) = softmax(s)
\end{array}
$$

I'll refer to the paper for the description of the single functions, but you can clearly see that the "softmax" is involved, which leads me to think that maybe what this network would generate is a set of parameters describing a probability. Therefore the final graph would be obtained by maximizing such probability.

This explanation makes sense to me since it would be possible to backpropagate,
but I need confirmation.

Am I right? Is there something more involved that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the model is trained by maximizing log likelihood. However it's an autoregressive model, not a variational encoder.

> However the first doubt I have is how to make this decisions differentiable

Well it's the same thing as an RNN really -- you only have to make discrete "decisions" when sampling from the model, while training can be done without.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate more on why the "training can be done without"?

Comment: well in training, you have the ground truth graph already, so instead of making discrete decisions you only ever have to calculate the probability of having made the ground truth already-known decisions.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, if you do backpropagation you would first run a forward pass, which in this context in my mind would be to perform these "decisions", then you backpropagate.

Comment: Hi, I've read the paper in more detail. I still think I'm missing bits. Can you roughly explain what do you mean with auto-regressive model?

Comment: yes, i mean that the probability of a graph is decomposed into a sequence of steps.

Comment: Is it a technical term from probability then? So I can look it up.